# Webserver with local domains

Tags: pi-3, networking, web-server

I'm creating a website on my Pi 3 and I want to link domains with the HTML folder to make it easier to access in the local network.

I want to achieve the following:

**192.168.0.1 -> localhost**

**mydomain.net -> 192.168.0.1/mydomain/**

**test.mydomain.net -> 192.168.0.1/mydomain/test**

I'm using an Apache 2.0 webserver. I tried it with lighttpd if anyone knows that, but I wasn't successful!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is handled by your web server configuration. However, you don't mention which server you are using. Second, this is not specific to the Pi and is off-topic per the site's FAQ.

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Please take discussions about policies and changes thereof to the site's meta. Comment flags can't be utilized that way.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using apache.

You can use virtual host, each virtual host detect the FQDN in the url (host + domain name) and direct it to the correct virtual host.

Ref.: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-8

Comment: I realize you are trying to help, but generally, you should not assume. Rather, you should ask for clarification via a comment.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.